How many Popes' portraits can fit on the walls of the Basilica of St. Paul Outside the Walls?
I was watching a video series on the Rosary at a men's group this morning and they were talking about all the popes on the walls at the Basilica of St. Paul Outside the Walls and it was mentioned that it was super cool that all the Popes were on the walls - I think the portraits of the Popes roughly matches what is on the scrollbar of the vatican.va site.
What I'm wondering (and this is not wholly idle speculation because maybe when they run out of space we'll be at the last Pope and that'll mark the eschaton) is how many spaces do they have left and is there a plan for where they'd put popes if they do run out of space?
I've never been there before so maybe I'm off base and there are choirs of popes and they won't have a problem for 3000 years, but I think the question can still be answered either way.

I have to admit, when I saw this on the front page, I wondered why, and in what manner, someone wanted actual Popes on walls... Hopefully adding "portraits" makes it more obvious that this is a legitimate, interesting question.

@Matthew thank you for that - it is distressing, however, to note that the Vatican still hasn't fixed the padding on that scrollbar.

I'll let someone else look up the answer to this to get the Internet votes, but apparently there is an answer to this question and it does portend the end of the world.

is this a Christianity question or a math question? It is an interesting question, it has an answer, but the only relevance is the pictures are of popes. If the pictures were of cats it wouldn't be relevant. This isn't a doctrinal question either. Seems off topic

@depperm there are a couple of reasons why I think this is on topic, but you'd really have to be Catholic to get it.  The relevance isn't simply the pictures of the popes, but the primacy of the basilica.  A Catholic asking a question about the architecture of one of the Basilicas is as topical as a Muslim asking about the dimensions of the big black box in Mecca on the Islam site.

There are six spots left after Pope Francis:

... With a new portrait being added with each new pope, it’s getting pretty tight with only six spaces left. This, according to some, may portend the end times.
According to a local legend the pope whose face graces that last space in the row will in fact be the final pope as the Second Coming begins. While this is simply apocryphal and not condoned by the Catholic church

Source: atlasobscura, the article was published on Sep 23, 2014, thus after Pope Francis's papacy began on 13 March 2013.

@PeterTurner The next 6 popes better be younger when they were elected, and also healthy.  If Pope Francis can rule 6 more years and if on average each pope rules 25 years, the end of the world will be approximately the year of 2180, still earlier than year 6000 in the Jewish Calendar, which is year 2240 on the Gregorian Calendar we use today.

How many Popes' portraits can fit on the walls of the Basilica of St. Paul Outside the Walls?
The short answer is 265 of popes, plus eight (8) empty places for future popes.
Many years ago, while visiting this basilica, I wondered if the empty medallions of the popes would in fact ever be filled in. After all, legend has it that when the last one is filled in, the end of the world would be imminent. Personally, I do not believe this.
When I visited this basilica in the 1990s, there were only two empty spots, so it is obvious that every so often they increase the empty medallion spots in order to create room for future popes. I am unaware if there is any more room for any more empty future medallion spots, but the walls must be very close to being filled in if not full.
There are at present eight (8) empty medallions left.

Around the walls are medallions representing the popes from St. Peter to Pope Francis. Only recent ones are realistic portraits. Legend tells us that when St. Paul’s runs out of space for these portraits, the world will come to an end. Don’t worry, there are spaces for at least eight more popes! - The Basilica of St. Paul Outside the Wall

